# Using anonymous types with T4 Templates for class generation

Tags: c#-4.0, t4, anonymous-types

I want to generate a bunch of similar classes based on enum values. These classes will be closely related in structure but due to the type safety of C# it is not really feasible to use inheritance to solve this problem. It is therefore preferable to use T4. In my case, I would like to use anonymous types in my metaprogramming code.

Here is a minimal snippet for the purpose of illustrating my usage pattern in a way that also exemplifies the problem I am running into:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using Fin4.Controls.Core;

<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    var enum_values = new dynamic[] {
        new { EnumName = "HoverDatePicker.Mode", Value = "View"},
        new { EnumName = "HoverDatePicker.Mode", Value = "Mode"},
        new { EnumName = "Frequency", Value = "Monthly"},
        new { EnumName = "Frequency", Value = "Weekly"}
    };
#>
<#
for(int i = 0; i < enum_values.Length; i++)
{ #>
    public class <#= enum_values[i].Value #>VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    }
<# 
} #>
```

This is saved in a file named `example.tt`. The Custom Tool selected for this file is `TextTemplatingFileGenerator`. When I (attempt to) compile my solution, the following output is generated:

```
ErrorGeneratingOutput
```

The following errors are also generated:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   Fin4    x:\code\project\project\Controls\example.cs 1   Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'ErrorGeneratingOutput' does not exist in the current context. Fin4    x:\code\project\project\Controls\example.cs 1   Active
Error       Compiling transformation: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'   Fin4    X:\code\project\project\Controls\example.tt 25
```

My first attempt to resolve this problem was add a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp`. My reference points to the following dll:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll`

This did not fix the problem. My second attempt to resolve the issue was to change the Custom Tool setting to `TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor`. This produced a file that appears to do something entirely different from what I want, so this did not fix the problem as well.

It seems clear that something is blocking the `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` tool from using the anonymous typing features of C# .NET 4.0. But I am unclear on how to enable that. I have done a lot of googling and nobody else seems to have this problem.

If someone could help me figure out how to use anonymous types with T4 class generators that would be incredibly helpful. So thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I ultimately got this working by **explicitly specifying** that C# 4.0 should be used for metaprogramming:

```
<# // Specify the C# version being used is 4.0 #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" #>

<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    var enum_nvs = new dynamic[] {
        new { EnumName = "HoverDatePicker.Mode",    EnumValue = "View"},
        new { EnumName = "HoverDatePicker.Mode",    EnumValue = "Edit"},
        new { EnumName = "Frequency",               EnumValue = "Monthly"},
        new { EnumName = "Frequency",               EnumValue = "Weekly"}
    };
#>
<#
for(int i = 0; i < enum_values.Length; i++)
{ #>
    public class <#= enum_values[i].Value #>VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    }
<# 
} #>
```

Comment: Interesting helpful answer, but to a different question. Your answer shows how to use "dynamic" from T4. Your question can be addressed by not using 'dynamic' You might want to amend your question or answer. (BTW your answer has typos and will not compile as written: enum_nvs != enum_values)

Answer (score 0):

The original question can be answered by removing the unneeded dynamic keyword:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    var enum_values = new /* OMIT dynamic */ [] {
        new { EnumName = "HoverDatePicker.Mode", Value = "View"},
        new { EnumName = "HoverDatePicker.Mode", Value = "Mode"},
        new { EnumName = "Frequency", Value = "Monthly"},
        new { EnumName = "Frequency", Value = "Weekly"}
    };
#>
<#
for(int i = 0; i < enum_values.Length; i++)
{ #>
    public class <#= enum_values[i].Value #>VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
    }
<# 
} #>
```